# Why there is multiple output in iterator it should only one at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, iteration

```
lis = ["x"]
a = input()
hd = iter(a.split(","))
while(1):
        val = next(hd, 'end')
        if val == 'end':
            break
        else:
            
            for i in lis:
                if i == val:
                    print(val)
                    
                else:
                    lis.append(val)
                    print("f",val)
```

> This is giving following output for this Input `hello,how,who`

```
f hello
hello
f how
f how
how
how
f who
f who
f who
f who
who
who
who
who
```

but output should be

```
f hello
f how
f who
```

why output without `f` is coming.
Inside while loop it should break at `'end'`. And in `lis` only `x` is there so according to code only `else` part should be executed so why `if` part is also executing and even multiple times Why??

Comment: for one thing input needs to have a prompt

Comment: @HezekiahBodine Input does not *need* a prompt.

Comment: after the value is appended to the list it is on the list so it goes to the for i in lis for the next bit

Comment: @HezekiahBodine This is not full program so this just part of it which causing problem

Comment: if val is in the list you want to print, and if val is not in the list you want to add it to the list, then val is in the list so it is printed... I think this is impossible to solve unless it is changed dramatically

Comment: Generally, I think it is a bad idea to modify a list that you are iterating over

Answer (score 0):

```
lis = ["x"]
a = input('please enter some values separated by commas and ending in end')
hd = iter(a.split(","))
while True:
    val = next(hd, 'end')
    if val == 'end':
        break
    else:
        while val not in lis:
            lis.append(val)
            print("f", val)
```

This has a new format but it does return what you want

Comment: I need one condition in which val is already in list because at that time I have to update it.

Comment: if val is on list it resets to the beginning of the while true loop

Comment: How it reset list please explain?

Comment: it doesnt reset to zero it just goes back to 'while True'